# TensorFlow Error tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/http_request.cc:334

Tags: macos, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage

I'm having an error with TensorFlow that didn't occur before:
I'm running TensorFlow locally with data (TFRecords) stored on google cloud storage. I'm using tf.contrib.Estimator and I save checkpoints of my graph's weights to cloud storage.

Everything worked fine.
Then I tried to run the code on cloud-ml on GPU's. This worked, however now returning to my local environment, and removing the code for the GPU's, it stopped working. I get the following error :

> F tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/http_request.cc:334] Check failed:
> that->post_body_read_ <= that->post_body_buffer_.size()

And it happens as I'm writing my checkpoint files to cloud storage for the first time. I tried running the same code on two different computers and it works on Windows but it doesn't work on macOS:

setup1:
tf version 1.2
macOS Sierra

setup2:
tf version 1.2
Windows 10

Comment: I get the exact same error, but on a new project that worked fine with local folders and local training. I double check the bucket url and data files, everything is correct. In My case the error occurs after this log message: `INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.`

Comment: Yes, with me it's after the same log message! 
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and 'fixed' it by using tensorflow rc1.3

Comment: Please give references, link to documents, etc.

Comment: What "fixed" it for me was todays update of the mac gcloud command line tools. Using a local job directory but training data in a cloud bucket works now with Tensorflow 1.2, OSX Sierra and Google Cloud SDK 163.0.0